# AngularJS : why is searching not working properly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to search text on table using angular ..I am able to search text in table .But my search works when I press enter or “search button” .Example when I write “Active” it not show the result but when I press enter or press search button it show the output .can we do the like search like autocomplete .Example when I press “a’ it show all item which start from “a” .Then if user write “ac” then show “ac” value ..same like that .when user write “active “ it show rows which have “active” without using search button or enter .can we make add filter so that it works properly ?

here is my code

```
$scope.searchInvoices = function(evt, queryval) {
        $scope.haveNorecordFound = true;

        if (typeof queryval != "undefined" && queryval.length === 0 || evt.keyCode === 13 || evt.type === 'click') {
            if (typeof queryval == "undefined" || queryval.length === 0) {
                console.log("if===")

                isfilterOccured = false;
                $scope.tasklist_records = $scope.total_tasklist_records;
                $scope.totalNumberOfrecord = $scope.tasklist_records.length + " records found."
            } else {
                console.log("esle===")
                var recordset = $scope.serachObject;
                results = [];
                var recordsetLength = recordset.length;
                var searchVal = queryval.toLowerCase();
                var i, j;

                for (i = 0; i < recordsetLength; i++) {
                    var record = recordset[i].columns;

                    for (j = 0; j < record.length; j++) {
                        if (record[j].value != null) {
                            var invoice = record[j].value.toLowerCase();
                            if (invoice.indexOf(searchVal) >= 0) {
                                results.push(recordset[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var nameOrPathValues = results.map(function(o) {
                    var result = {};
                    o.columns.forEach(function(c) {
                        result[c.fieldNameOrPath] = c.value;
                    });
                    return result;
                });
                console.log("serach");

                console.log(nameOrPathValues);

                var objectarray = nameOrPathValues.map(function(o) {
                    var result = {};
                    collectNameOrPath.forEach(function(name) {
                        result[name] = o[name];
                    });
                    return result;
                });
                isfilterOccured = true;


                $scope.tasklist_records = objectarray;
                if ($scope.tasklist_records.length == 0) {
                    $scope.haveNorecordFound = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.totalNumberOfrecord = $scope.tasklist_records.length + " records found."
                }



            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Your fiddle is not working, try `data-ng-keyup` instead of `ng-keyup`

Comment: please type "active" then press enter .it show data .but I need to show search data without enter

Comment: Are you sure your plunker is working ? Please check it again

Comment: create a new plunker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82260/discussion-between-user944513-and-vineet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging in code, I found that you're biding function on either `enter button press` or `search click`. That's why it was not working on `ng-keyup`. Please replace your function from below code.

```
$scope.searchInvoices = function(evt, queryval) {
      console.log(queryval)
      $scope.haveNorecordFound = true;
      var recordset = $scope.serachObject;
                results = [];
                var recordsetLength = recordset.length;
                var searchVal = queryval.toLowerCase();
                var i, j;

                for (i = 0; i < recordsetLength; i++) {
                    var record = recordset[i].columns;

                    for (j = 0; j < record.length; j++) {
                        if (record[j].value != null) {
                            var invoice = record[j].value.toLowerCase();
                            if (invoice.indexOf(searchVal) >= 0) {
                                results.push(recordset[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                var nameOrPathValues = results.map(function(o) {
                    var result = {};
                    o.columns.forEach(function(c) {
                        result[c.fieldNameOrPath] = c.value;
                    });
                    return result;
                });
                console.log("serach");

                console.log(nameOrPathValues);

                var objectarray = nameOrPathValues.map(function(o) {
                    var result = {};
                    collectNameOrPath.forEach(function(name) {
                        result[name] = o[name];
                    });
                    return result;
                });
                isfilterOccured = true;


                $scope.tasklist_records = objectarray;
                if ($scope.tasklist_records.length == 0) {
                    $scope.haveNorecordFound = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.totalNumberOfrecord = $scope.tasklist_records.length + " records found."
                }

    };
```